# g++ expects an unqualified-id, but what is it expecting?

Tags: c++, templates, types, casting, type-alias

I'm following a lesson on type aliases in a c++ book, and tried compiling the code below:

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>

template <typename To, typename From>
struct NarrowCaster const { //first error points here
    To cast(From value) {
        const auto converted = static_cast<To>(value);
        const auto backwards = static_cast<From>(converted);
        if(value != backwards) throw std::runtime_error{ "Narrowed!" };
        return converted;
    }
};

template <typename From>
using short_caster = NarrowCaster<short, From>; //second error

int main(){
    try {
        const short_caster<int> caster;
        const auto cyclic_short = caster.cast(142857); //third error
        printf("cyclic_short: %d\n", cyclic_short);
    }catch(const std::runtime_error& e) {
        printf("Exception: %s\n", e.what());
    }
}
```

unfortunately, g++ (or clang++, because I'm using OS X) says this:
`typealias.cpp|5 col 27 error| expected unqualified-id`
which seems to also cause 2 more errors:

```
typealias.cpp|15 col 34 error| expected ';' after alias declaration
typealias.cpp|19 col 27 error| variable has incomplete type 'const short_caster<int>' (aka 'const NarrowCaster')
typealias.cpp|5 col 8 error| note: forward declaration of 'NarrowCaster'
```

I've tried fixing this issue, I'm already using std=c++17, and checked for non-ascii characters and made sure there aren't any differences from the code in the book. What am I doing wrong?

compiler command, if it helps:

`g++ typealias.cpp -o typealias -std=c++17`

Comment: (`struct NarrowCaster const {`) That `const` doesn't go there. Maybe you mean to put it on the `cast()` function?

Comment: moving the ```const``` keyword to ```const To cast(From value)``` returns this error: ```'this' argument to member function 'cast' has type 'const short_caster<int>' (aka 'const NarrowCaster<short, int>'), but function is not marked const```

Comment: I also tried compiling with the c++11 and 20 standard, both don't work.

Comment: You would do it as `To cast(From value) const {...}`

Answer (score 0):

```
struct NarrowCaster const {...
```

The `const` goes after a member function which means the function will not modify any data members:

```
To cast(From value) const {...}
```